# How to sniff IM comunicaton?

Tags: sniffing, sniffer

I would like to write a communication sniffer for some IM, like ICQ or MSN. Can you please help me how to start? It's quite hard to find useful info how to do this. How should I start? I know that there is the winpcap library for windows that it is good for packet sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

- Search for the specification of the IM protocol you want to sniff
- Learn how to use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or similar e.g: [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/)
- Download and study the source code of a IM Client, for example [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)

Comment: libpcap and winpcap can parse a bunch of protocols, you could start studying how it works.
Also, you could make some captures to learn about the protocols involved

Comment: The tool for packet capturing is wireshark: www.wireshark.org

Comment: If you're coding in C# you can get SharpPcap (a pcap wrapper for C#) to start. FYI, writing an application like you describe is not trivial though.